# opencv with visual studio 2010 error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

I am trying to build my first opencv application, I added the include directories and the library directories and then added the linking input which is some opencv.lib files after running this code:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Mat im = imread("c:/full/path/to/lena.jpg");
    if (im.empty()) 
    {
        cout << "Cannot load image!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    imshow("Image", im);
    waitKey(0);
}
```

but I got this error:

> The program can't start because libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is missing from your computer.

the error list include:

> Warning   1   warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '-static-libgcc' c:\Users\Kato\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\cvtest\cvtest\cl    cvtest

I added -static-libgcc to command line additional options but the same error.

Comment: `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` and `-static-libgcc` are specific to MinGW, not to Visual Studio.

Comment: I know but this error is in visual studio 2010 ultimate and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @AhmedKato Andrey Kamaev just gave you a clue. Ask yourself "Why do I get a MinGW error in VS 2010 ultimate." You start solving a problem with visiting clues.

Comment: OpenCV with C++ requires a Visual C++ compiler. Try creating a new EMPTY Visual C++ project with OpenCV dependencies and lib directories